# Google Colab is telling me that a path to a video input is not set when it clearly is set correctly

Tags: computer-vision, google-colaboratory, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I am using google colab GPU to run an [open source vehicle counting system](https://github.com/nicholaskajoh/ivy) on the darknet/yolov3 framework. I was able to get yolov3 running perfectly for video object detection. I cannot get this second repository to run and I think it is a google colab issue because I am new to it. Ivy-master and darknet-master are cloned under content, I also tried saving these in drive but it did not make a difference.
I have my .env file set up as vars.env and installed the colab-env. When I run !python -m main in colab, I get the error Path to video or camera input not set. My variable in my vars.env file looks like so: 
`VIDEO="./content/vehiclesystem/data/demodata/videos/sample.mp4".` The path is correct, so why is colab telling me the path is not set? I have tried asking owner for help but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think the path should not contain the `.` (dot). But for certain results, try to go to the files panel on the left side and find the path by right-clicking the mp4 file and selecting `Copy Path` option.

Paste this path into your variable in my `vars.env` file. It should work now :)